# Applescript: "can't get tab group 1 of window "System Preferences"

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator, system-settings

I tried to run the script using Automator [from this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312757/function-keys-function-toggle/312765):

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window 1
    click checkbox "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" of tab group 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

It works only when the checkbox in System Preferences is enabled, else (checkbox is disabled) I get the error:

```
The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: Can’t get tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.”

System Events got an error: Can’t get tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.
```

So, fn toggling doesn't works.

I use MacBook on M1 chip with Monterey.

What should I do to run the script clearly? How can I modify the script to make it works? Why it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my **MBP**, running **macOS Big Sur (11.5.2)**, I don’t have `checkbox "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"`. In System Pref’s, mine is `checkbox  "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys on external keyboards"`

[image]

I added `delay` commands and updated the text value of `checkbox "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"` to `checkbox 3`. So far this has passed everyone of my tests.

These edits work for me.

```
if application "System Preferences" is running then do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
repeat until application "System Preferences" is not running
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell window "Keyboard" of process "System Preferences"
    repeat until checkbox 3 of tab group 1 exists
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell its tab group 1
        click checkbox 3
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.1
quit application "System Preferences"
```

---

> It works only when the checkbox in System Preferences is enabled, else
> (checkbox is disabled) I get the error:

The value of `checkbox`’s attribute AXEnabled will always be true, whether or not the checkbox is "checked or not checked". The value of `checkbox`’s attribute AXEnabled can’t be set or un-set.

That can be checked with this following **AppleScript** code.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell window "Keyboard" of process "System Preferences"
    repeat until checkbox 3 of tab group 1 exists
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell its tab group 1 to tell its checkbox 3
        tell its attribute "AXEnabled" to set canBeDisabled to settable
    end tell
end tell

return canBeDisabled
```

I’m assuming the OP is referring to the `checkbox` being enabled or disabled to being "checked or not checked"

Comment: The OP states "It works only when the checkbox in System Preferences is enabled, else (checkbox is disabled) I get the error: ..." and if the `checkbox` is _disabled_ in that the _value_ of its _attribute_ `AXEnabled` is e.g. `NO` of `false`, then I'd have to assume the _code_ in this answer will fail too under the condition mentioned in the OP.

Comment: If as stated in the OP and the `checkbox` is _disabled_ in that the _value_ of its _attribute_ `AXEnabled` is e.g. `NO` of `false` then this code will fail. There is a big difference between _checked/unchecked_ and _enabled/disabled_ and the OP clearly states the later. BTW The OP never mentioned using an external keyboard, only MacBook on M1 chip with Monterey.

Comment: @user3439894 the edits in my post should address your comments.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the line

```
delay 0.25
```

after the line

```
reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
```

shown in your AppleScript.

I suppose a delay of 0.25 seconds may not be enough. The example below tries to click 10 times over a period of at least 2.25 seconds. Once a click succeeds no further attempts are made.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window 1
    repeat with i from 10 to 1 by -1
        try
            click checkbox "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" of tab group 1
            exit repeat
        on error
            if i = 1 then
                display alert "Failed to click" as critical
            else
                delay 0.25
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```